# JobSheduler complex rules

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-jobscheduler

I'm trying to implement a complex, time based, set of rules for scheduling jobs on `Android Lollipop`.
I need to run an `System API` and a `bulk insert` in the DB, so it shouldn't take more than 2-3 seconds. I'll call it **`JOB1`**.
The rules are:

1. Run `JOB1` at app startup (easy, just run an AsyncTask at Application onCreate).
2. Run `JOB1` every approximately 4 hours.
3. Run `JOB1` ONLY if it wasn't ran in the last 4 hours [optional - not even at app start time]
4. Run `JOB1` at exactly 23:59 (or 11:59pm), regardless of rule 3.

I don't think that a single instance of `JobScheduler` can follow all these rules or at least I still haven't figured it out.

BONUS QUESTION:

```
    JobScheduler jobs = (JobScheduler) getSystemService(JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE);
    JobInfo.Builder b = new JobInfo.Builder(SYNC_JOB_ID,
            new ComponentName(this, SyncJobService.class));
    b.setRequiredNetworkType(JobInfo.NETWORK_TYPE_NONE);
    b.setPeriodic(getPeriod(6)) //6 hours
            .setPersisted(true)
    jobs.schedule(b.build());
```

Calling this at `Application` startup will override the previous call or I'll have different instances of `JobScheduler` running every 6 hours?